# python-social-auth with django /?next= variable

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am using python-social-auth with django 1.7. I have the following code in my settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/add_college'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

However, when my url is like

```
accounts/login/?next=/display/Electronics/Random/
```

I want to be redirected to

```
display/Electronics/Random/
```

In my templates, I have the following code

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}" class="btn btn-social btn-facebook">
```

But, I am still redirected to the url specified in `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. How do I take the value of the `next` variable into account?

Comment: Did you add this line in your login page template: <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />

Comment: No, I hadn't added it before. It doesn't seem to work even after adding it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your settings.py:

```
from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```